# Convert DOCX File to PDF File Without Losing Form Fields

Tags: python, pdf, form-fields, docx2pdf

I'm tasked with converting a directory of DOCX files to PDF files.  It's critical that each document's form-fields are preserved during the process.  Each of these files contains several (at times, dozens) of form fields, and it's impractical to manually add the form fields back as there are hundreds of DOCX files to convert.

So far, I've tried using Python's *docx2pdf* package to batch convert the directory via CLI.  While it successfully converted the documents to a PDF form, it failed to retain the form fields.  Creating a program (instead of relying on the package's CLI tools) yielded the same results.

Am I perhaps using the wrong package?  From what I understand, this is the best Python package to use for this process.

Comment: If there are no easy solutions and you absolutely need this feature, you could use pymupdf and python-docx to implement it yourself - but it would not be an easy task.